# How to load external properties file and override springboot application.properties (without runtime args)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I want to load properties file that is outside the springboot app and override the sprignboot matched application properties on the run time environment Programmatically not through server context/ runtime args?

I have found a way to implement this by creating listener for ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent.
working code example link:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment

But looking for much more easy and spring boot managed solution

something like this (below code is not working though) :

```
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MainApplication.class);
application.setBannerMode(Mode.OFF);
Properties props = new Properties();
try{
 props.load(newFileInputStream(
   "C:\\...\\PropFile\\applicationconfig.properties"));
application.setDefaultProperties(props);
application.run(args);
} catch (Exception e) {
//print exception here;
}
```

Comment: you can take a look this tutorial baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties

Comment: `"C:\\...\\PropFile\\applicationconfig.properties"));`. Don't you think this path is wrong? there is nothing as such `...`.

Comment: @Jonathan,
i will try and let you know (One thing i saw in tutorial is we have to pass the file path as an CL argument. In my case i do not have that option).

Comment: @ialam,
im just giving an example of the path. i know "..." is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same using spring `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

```
public class EnvironmentPostProcessorExample implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    private final YamlPropertySourceLoader loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        Resource path = new ClassPathResource("com/example/myapp/config.yml");
        PropertySource<?> propertySource = loadYaml(path);
        environment.getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
    }
    private PropertySource<?> loadYaml(Resource path) {
        if (!path.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Resource " + path + " does not exist");
        }
        try {
            return this.loader.load("custom-resource", path, null);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to load yaml configuration from " + path, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

[spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners)